# memory usage of apps by automating

Tags: android, docker, performance-testing

I want to test memory usage of apps by automating. How can I measure memory usage of my android app after running it for an hour with a tool or other options like Docker,.. automatically ?  I tried systrace but I couldn't see maximum or minimum memory usage.

Comment: Use cAdvisor to monitor the container?

Comment: @Yuankun can I use it to test memory usage of apps ?

Comment: Sure you can. Besides cAdvisor, there are many other performance measurement tools for container.

Comment: @Yuankun Thank you so much, I'll try learning and using it.

Comment: @Yuankun  other performance measurement tools ? Could you share their names with me, please ?

Comment: Such as Netdata or Sisdig.